How to crop a PDF file in Libre Office Draw?
I just returned from a copy shop where I got my university diploma scanned. The paper is DIN A3 form and each site are basically two DIN A4 next to each other. They sent it as one PDF file and I just need to select half of the page but can't figure out how to do it. Well, I figured I can just do a screenshot and create a new PDF from the image, but there must be a "proper" way?

Does this LibreOffice help file answer your question?

Open the .pdf file in LibreOffice Draw which has a Crop Image tool which looks like two overlapping right angles in its toolbar. When the Crop Image tool is selected it turns red and red handles appear on the corners and edges of the image (in this case the .pdf) which can be dragged to crop the image to the desired size. Then use either File -> Export As… to export the cropped .pdf file as a PDF document or File -> Save As… to save the cropped .pdf file as a different image format.
Alternatively you can install GIMP with sudo apt install gimp and use the crop tool in GIMP which looks like some kind of hollow square to crop the pdf to the desired size. Then you can use File -> Export As… to export the cropped .pdf file as a PDF or as any other image format that is supported by GIMP. Alternatively you can make a backup copy of the original .pdf file and use File -> Overwrite to overwrite the original .pdf file with its cropped version.

Thank you, that makes much more sense.
Still not solved though, I keep getting the cropped site sitting in a large white field. When I resize to A4 and change "landscape" to "portrait" and drag the page to the correct position (which seems correct at that point), after exporting it's about 50% of the page and 50% white field.
I also tried to copy the selection and create a new file (in LibreOffice Draw) and curiously it looked OK in the preview and when opened in Document Viewer, but when I opened it in LibreOffice Draw again (to save it compressed) the cropped site was still there. Weird.

I'm unable to replicate your results even though cropping my sample pdf tested 100% correctly in my LibreOffice Draw. Please send me a link to an example pdf document, so that I can download it and test cropping your sample document in my LibreOffice Draw. I find GIMP image editor to be an easier to use editor for cropping my PDFs.
